# ClickHouse: how to enable performant queries against increasing user-defined attributes

Tags: clickhouse

I am designing a system that handles a large number of buried point event. An event record contains:

- buried_point_id, for example: 1 means app_launch, 2 means user_register.
- happened_at: the event timestamp.
- user_id: the user identifier.
- other attributes, including basic ones (phone_number, city, country) and user-defined ones (click_item_id, it literally can be any context information). PMs will add more and more user-defined attributes to the event record.

The query pattern is like:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM buried_points WHERE buried_point_id = 1 AND city = 'San Francisco' AND click_item_id = 123;
```

Since my team invests heavily in ClickHouse, I want to leverage ClickHouse for the problem. I wonder if it is a good practice to use the experimental [Map data type](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en//sql-reference/data-types/map/) to store all attributes in a `MAP`-type column such as {city: San Francisco, click_item_id: 123, ...}, or any other recommendation? Thanks.

Comment: Does I understand correctly, that number of such attributes not fixed and unknown on the table creation? If if's fixed it's better to create separate columns for known attributes. Otherwise you can also use store string representing data in json and use [json functions](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/) to access. It will require de-serializing json from string every time, but it may be suitable for some cases

Comment: Hi @Deffe, yes your understand is correct. Do you know how json functions compared to [map](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en//sql-reference/data-types/map/) in terms of query performance?

Comment: I suppose that map can be faster, but it is really depends on data. It's better to test on sample dataset.

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar issue right now with mutable attributes, have you found a workaround for this @PangFish?